# How to customize the background color of a UITableViewCell in xamarin ios?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I would like to customize the background of all of the UITableViewCells within my UITableView. So far I have not been able to customize them.

Take a look here :[TableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7nWJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

In your GetCell method, just do:

```
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {
              //Do cell stuff here
            MyTestCell myCell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("MyTestCell") as MyTestCell;
              .......
              .........
              myCell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
            }
```

This way, all your UITableView cells will have the color that you set it to!